# Tap on entire row in ListView Flutter layout

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

So I have a settings screen which is a `ListView` and I want the user to be able to tap on the entire list row to change that setting. However, I can't seem to find a non-insane way of expanding the child of the `GestureDetector` to fill up the entire horizontal space.

My listview:

```
ListView(
    children: [
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          print('tapped the row');
        },
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text('Totals expressed in', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0)),
              Text('Percentages', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 15.0)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Divider(height: 1.0),
      // followed by other elements in the list view
```

This will detect the tap but only the space the text elements take up horizontally (a fraction of the width of the screen). I know about the `Expanded` widget, but wherever I try to put it I get an error that it either must be a descendant of the `Row` or `Column` or the exception:

> RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Code change - `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start` to:

```
Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch
```

This will make the Column children to take up all horizontal Space.

Answer (score 6):

Try InkWell. InkWell allows the clickable space to stretch for the whole row.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using a Container with a transparent background color to solve this issue.